# What are the differences of that iterations?

Tags: javascript, variables, loops

What are the differences of that iterations:

```
var recordId;
for(recordId in deleteIds){
  ...
}
```

and

```
for(var recordId in deleteIds){
  ...
}
```

It says implicit definition(what is it), is there a performance difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the two samples are equivalent, however the first may come from following a recommended pattern in JavaScript which is declaring all variables at the top of every function.

Sample:

```
var recordId,
    i = 0;

for(recordId in deleteIds){
  ...
  i++;
}
```

More explanation on this can be found here [JSLint error: Move all 'var' declarations to the top of the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646455/jslint-error-move-all-var-declarations-to-the-top-of-the-function)

Answer (score 1):

An "implicit declaration" is a variable that is assigned a value before it is declared using a `var`. The scenario leaves the variable declared in the largest possible scope (the "global" scope).

However, in both your code examples, `recordId` is declared before it is assigned (`var recordId`), so there's no problem.

As to your other question, no, there is no noticeable performance difference.