# How to make JSLint scan the whole file?

Tags: javascript, notepad++, jslint

I am using JSLint to scan some Javascript code for potential errors. I'm using Notepad++ with the JSLint plugin. The problem is - it just scans, say `x%` of file and then stops. I have unchecked the *Stop on first error* option too but I get the same result. It still stops after scanning only a part of rhe file. Is there anyway to make JSLint scan the whole file instead of some *percent* of file?

Edit:

I've set the `maxerr` option to 10000, but the scan stops at just 41 errors and displays (1% scanned)

Edit 2:

Currently, my JSLint options look like this:

`/*jslint indent: 50, maxerr: 10000, passfail: false, safe: true, adsafe: true, debug: true, evil: false, continue: true, css: false, on: false, fragment: false, es5: true, bitwise: true, regexp: false, eqeq: true */`

Comment: How to look at JSLint options?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a maximum number of errors option that defaults to 50

> Maximum number of errors `maxerr`  The maximum number of warnings reported. (default is 50)

You can see all the options on the [jsLint website](http://www.jslint.com/help.html).

Set it to a few thousand and it should be fine :)

#### Update

This seems to be a [special case for having variables not at the top of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646455/jslint-error-move-all-var-declarations-to-the-top-of-the-function).  You can try setting `undef` or `vars` to true.  If you don't like that you might consider jsHint, a fork of jsLint thats designed to be more configurable.

Comment: I had changed that too. Please see the edit. However, I get the same result.

Comment: The error is :
`Move 'var' declarations to the top of the function`

Comment: Do you get the same results when using the website that you do with your notepad plugin?

Comment: Its not actually a website. I'm scanning the javascript files of Google Chrome extensions on the Chrome Web Store. So the context of _using the website_ or _using the javascript file_ doesn't apply here. :(

Comment: No sorry I mean when you use the jsLint website to scan your code.  see jslint.com

Comment: I did a scan using the website just now. It stops at the same point.

Comment: Ok, updated, looks like this is a special case that shortcircuits it.

Comment: The update seems to be useful. Upvoting your answer. :)
However, I'll have to verify before confirming whether this is the exact reason for my problem.

Answer (score 8):

I had this same problem of it stopping after it reached 2% or so.

It seems as though JSLint does NOT like `for statements`. In their "read the instructions" page it even says that you shouldn't use for statements. Which I know you shouldn't use `for (var x in y)` statements, but I think that `for (var x = 0; x < array.length; x++)` is fine normally. But JSLint does not like it, and will give the "move vars to the top of function error" and then stop the rest of the code from scanning.

So to fix this, I just moved the two for statements I had in my code, and then it scanned just fine.

Answer (score 2):

What's the actual error message when it stops? It's entirely possible that it's simply come across a parsing error that it can't get past. In which case, your remedy is to fix what JSLint is complaining about before it will process the whole file.

Comment: As I mentioned in one of the comments, it stops giving the following message: `Move 'var' declarations to the top of the function. Stopping (1% scanned)`

Comment: Sorry for missing that.  Looking at [the source](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js#L3835), it seems that's just a fatal error and there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

**JSLint** will often stop before it checks the entire document. Also, the `maxerr` option does not exist in the current version of **JSLint**.

Answer (score 0):

its stoping because its reaching the maxerr JSLint setting. you can increase this setting.