# Test for innerText or textContent inside loop

Tags: javascript

JSLint throws the following error that I am not sure how to resolve:

Error: Don't declare variables in a loop.

Line: var text = item.innerText || item.textContent

My question is how do I get for support of innerText or textContent and use the correct method while looping through elements?

Here's my example.  I am writing the class of the elements next to the text. I'd like to have the same results, but test for innerText or textContent outside of the for-loop.

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/PwwjK/

HTML:

```
<p class="test">1</p>
<p class="test">2</p>
<p class="test">3</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  var list = $('.test');

  for (var i = 0, item; item = list[i]; i++) {

    if (i === 1) {
        //Add new class attribute.
        item.className = item.className + ' hello';
    };

    var text = item.innerText || item.textContent

    item.innerHTML = text + ' ' + item.className;

  };

}());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to declare `var text` outside the for-loop for this test to pass.

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  var list = $('.test'),
      text; // text is declared here.

  for (var i = 0, item; item = list[i]; i++) {
    if (i === 1) {
        //Add new class attribute.
        item.className = item.className + ' hello';
    };

    text = item.innerText || item.textContent

    item.innerHTML = text + ' ' + item.className;
  };
}());
```

Also, here's a resourceful link that may have an answer as to why jsLint asks you to declare the variables on the top: [JSLint error: Move all 'var' declarations to the top of the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646455/jslint-error-move-all-var-declarations-to-the-top-of-the-function)

Comment: Thank you!  I've been trying to use JSLint to help me write better JavaScript and I think I just got stuck in a mental block on that one.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable outside the loop, and assign it inside the loop.

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  var list = $('.test');
  var text;

  for (var i = 0, item; item = list[i]; i++) {

    if (i === 1) {
        //Add new class attribute.
        item.className = item.className + ' hello';
    };

    text = item.innerText || item.textContent

    item.innerHTML = text + ' ' + item.className;

  };

}());
```