# JSHint: "Unexpected 'var'" in For Loop

Tags: javascript, jshint

I am running JSHint on my Javascript code to try and clean it up and it is giving me this warning:

```
 #3 Unexpected 'var'.
    for (var i = 0; i < self.myArray.length; i++) { // Line 88, Pos 14
```

Expanding this out, it is this piece of code:

```
self.myFunction = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < self.myArray.length; i++) {
        // Do some stuff
    }
};
```

I have searched the internet and seen many ways to write a `for` loop. Some use `var`, some don't, others use `let` etc.

I can't seem to find any info on how JSHint expects me to construct my for loop. Can anyone enlighten me on some best practice, or what JSHint is looking for?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does not JSLint allow "var" in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105006/why-does-not-jslint-allow-var-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: Yes, this answers it! Writing my loop like this fixes the scoping issue and the JSHint error (I think):

```
self.myFunction = function() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < self.myArray.length; i++) {
        // Do some stuff
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `var` then it will create the variable as the enclosed function scoped or global scope (if not inside a function).

So always use `let` in for loop, the scope will be only within for loop.

```
self.myFunction = function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < self.myArray.length; i++) {
        // Do some stuff
    }
};
```

Comment: I do not believe this solves the issue, at least standard JSLint will still complain.

Comment: This fixes the scoping issue, for sure, but I still get this error from JSHint `Unexpected 'let'.`.