# Move 'var' declarations to the top of the function error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to develop this code but an error occurs :

Move 'var' declarations to the top of the function.
for (var i = 0; i < extractPassword.length; i++){

The code:

```
var extractPassword = (['a', 'z','c']);
var newPass = [];
for (var i = 0; i < extractPassword.length; i++){
    var x = extractPassword[i];
    if ('a' <= x && x <= 'z') {
        newPass.push(0);
    }
}
return newPass;
```

Can you please help me correct it ?

Comment: What exactly is unclear about the error message? (alternatively, I'd suggest not using `var` at all - use at least ES2015 syntax of `const` / `let`)

Comment: I tried to declare the variables at the top but I dont understand why isnt working

Comment: No, you are not declaring your variables at the top of the function - change your code so that the variables are declared at the top, and it'll clear the error

Comment: I did it this way:   var extractPassword = (['a', 'z', 'c']);
var newPass = [];
var i = 0;
var x = '';
for (var i = 0; i < extractPassword.length; i++){
    var x = extractPassword[i];
 if ('a' <= x && x <= 'z') {
  newPass.push(0);
  }
 }
return newPass;

Comment: but the error was still there

Comment: You are still not declaring the variables at the top of the function. Identify the containing function, then declare the variables right inside it, instead of past other statements - or, like I said, don't use `var`, it's effectively obsolete nowadays

Comment: Aside: It's not really clear what `'a' <= x && x <= 'z'` is meant to be doing.

Comment: Just use `const` instead of `var`.  You're receiving a warning (probably from your IDE).  You should pretty much never be using `var` any more.  Use `const` or `let` and declare the variable in the appropriate scope (as you were doing), but use `const` instead of `var` for the `x` variable in that loop.

Comment: @jfriend00 It seems to me to be essentially to be a case of not reading the error message or not understanding what a function is or where the top of a function is located or something like that. Didn't seem like a useful question to have around. I voted to close as not reproducible, but probably should have closed in favor of https://stackoverflow.com/q/4646455. When an answer can be written in 60 seconds that's usually an indicator to take a step back and consider whether question really *should* be answered IMO

Comment: You should either accept the answer or write your own answer, but please don't post the answer into your question.

Comment: A conversation about handling this question from a curation perspective has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244059/discussion-on-question-by-kmart23-move-var-declarations-to-the-top-of-the-func).

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to declare the `x` outside use this piece of code

```
 var extractPassword = (['a', 'z','c']);
var x

var newPass = [];
for (let i = 0; i < extractPassword.length; i++){
     x = extractPassword[i];
    if ('a' <= x && x <= 'z') {
        newPass.push(0);
        }
    }
return newPass;
```